# c# - methods for declaring indefinite session?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently creating a project whereas there is like an "Add to Cart". I'm thinking about using a `Session[""]` But, the user can choose indefinite numbers of item from the database then just store them. And when they are ready to print the chosen data, they will just go to a page and I will display all the `Session` there. I'm thinking about `array` but declaring array needs definite value and i cannot carry that to any page the user will go.

Comment: how about `List<T>`

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with `List<T>` can it store session indefinitely and can   I add items to a `List<T>` anytime?

Comment: theoretically. but enough for shopping cart.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about - [collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145035(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or [persistence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx), and [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)?

Comment: I'm starting now in `List<T>` How can I display it if I already it's in a session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session object would be a good place to store the shopping cart, you can also store it in a cookie if you want it to persist across sessions. I wouldn't save it to the database until the purchase is complete and only keep complete orders in the db.

You can check some advice here:

http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/07/asp-net-mvc-do-you-know-where-your-tempdata-is/

and here

http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications

Comment: I like your latter advice but I'm not using MVC.

Comment: Yeah, what I want you to do is to get some idea. :D